# Reading multiple Excel files in Python into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I have multiple Excel files in a folder which I want to read in Python and save into multiple dataframes with the same file name as the Excel files.

I have tried many ways but nothing works:

```
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(r'C:\\Working\\Test', "*.xlsx" ))
```

Comment: Show your own effort (code) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: When I am adding code it is showing formatting issue and not allow to add

Comment: What kind of dataframes?

Comment: Show what you tried, even if it didn't work (and show the precise error message) as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: data frame from which I can extact the columns into another file

Comment: # append datasets to the list
for i in range(file_count):
    temp_df = pd.read_excel("./xlsx/"+files[i])
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)

Comment: That wasn't my question: There are various dataframe implementations, from the code in the last comment it looks like you mean **Pandas** dataframes (you have to add the resp. tag to the question). What is the code in the last comment supposed to mean? Please add additional information directly to the question (by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76294163/edit) it), not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Pandas library.

This is sample code (explanations in the comments):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

// Path of Folder containing the excel files
foler_path = "Your_Folder"

excel_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.xlsx') or f.endswith('.xls')]

# Loop through each Excel file
for excel_file in excel_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, excel_file)
    
    # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    
    # Save the DataFrame with the same file name as the Excel file
    df.to_csv(f'{file_path}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: `//` isn't used for comments in Python. Also: the asker hasn't mentioned CSV-files?